# Trouble getting menu to work

Tags: bash, menu

Currently I’m trying to get a menu working for my Into to Unix class. The problem I’m getting right now is that when I input something into the script my input appears instead of the script responding as how it should base on the input. But base on the book I should be doing it right since I followed the format that case is used, or so I think? What would I need to modify in order to make this work? Also the shell I'm using is bash.

This is the assignment I’m working on:

1. Write a case script that will give the choices to do the following:

   a. List the users of the /etc/passwd file that have a four digit ID number greater than 999.

   b. Show only the month, day, and year from the date command.

   c. Take the file of the user’s choosing and show all the letters in uppercase.

Here is the code I'm using at the moment

```
clear
if [ "$#" -ne 1 ]; then
    echo Press 1 for a list of users with the UID greater than 999
    echo Press 2 for the Day, Month, and Year
    echo Press 3 to show a file name from lower case to upper case
    read a
    exit
fi

case "$1" in
    1) awk -F: '($3>=999)  && ($3!=9999)' /etc/passwd ;;
    2) echo Todays date is: ; date | awk '{print $2, $3, $6}' ; sleep 1 ;;
    3) ls -aC | more ; echo What file would you like to change from lower case to uppercase?  ;read y ;sleep 1 ; clear ; echo $y | tr '[:lower:]' '[:upper:]' ; sleep 1 ;;
    *) echo Invalid input
esac
```

Comment: Ho do you run your script?

Comment: Sure you want to unconditionally `exit` after diplaying the options? No idea about what your teacher wants, but I would not accept that `date` piped into `awk`. (Which on my system displays “21 Nov,” as there `date` displays only 5 fields.) Try something like `date +'Today is %d %B %Y'` instead with no `awk`.

Comment: Again, not sure about what your teacher wants, but I have a feeling (s)he wants you to use `select`: http://pastebin.com/qTC59eur

Comment: @manatwork It seems to me that the exercise is aimed specifically at writing a `case` statement, which a `select` loop would supersede.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @manatwork noted in the comments, you don't want to `exit` right after the user enters their choice. Also, your `case` statement operates on `$1`, the first argument to the script (or the first positional parameter in Bash lingo). Logically, that's not what you want. You `read` the user's choice into `a`, so that's what you want to be `case`ing:

```
case "$a"
in
...
```